# Find out hadoop vendor

Tags: hadoop

I have inherited a `Hadoop` installation and I am interested to know how the previous admin installed it and where it came from. I am new to `Hadoop`, but it appears that the previous admin simple installed `Apache Hadoop` from source (rather than using `Cloudera`, `Hortonworks`, etc).

How can I validate this? The `LICENSE.txt` file says nothing about `Cloudera`, `Hortonworks`, etc, but an absence of something is not validation. If it had come from a commercial vendor, can I be sure that the `LICENSE.txt` file would have mentioned them by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run `hadoop version`

it should tell you what you need to know:

the version, where it's installed etc

if not, then try `which hadoop`

Comment: I know where it is installed, that it is Hadoop 1.1.1, and have access to all the directory information. Running `hadoop version` tells me:

`Hadoop 1.1.1`

`Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.1 -r 141110`

`Compiled by hortonfo on Mon Nov 19 10:48:11 UTC 2012`

`From source with checksum 9be520e845cf135867fb8b927a40affb`

Does this indicate that it was compiled from source via an apache tarball as I suspected? Nothing in the path mentions a vendor.

Comment: it means that it was compiled by user hortonfo on the date specified.  Hadoop is java so when you download the tarball and unpack it, it's essentially 'installed' (though not configured) - you usually don't need to build it yourself unless youre super awesome.  It looks like you have the regular apache version

Comment: That makes sense and is what I was expecting. To be sure, though, what information would be given from a `hadoop version` command if it was a cloudera or hortonworks distribution which would give this away?

Comment: for CDH, you'd should see something like '-cdhx.x.x' in the verison.  For horton works, you'd see something like '2.x.x.x.x.x.x.x - 2041' in the version.  Additionally, youd see a horton works or cloudera subversion url thingy